# In cosa consiste la "prova finestra"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Nella commedia *Morte accidentale di un anarchico* di Dario Fo ho letto:

> Nient’affatto... commentavo soltanto. E se mi
>   permette, io chiedo a lei, signorina Feletti, se ci ha presi per dei propagandatori di detersivi... dal momento che ci vuol vedere ad ogni costo intenti a fare **la prova
>   finestra** con ogni anarchico che ci capiti sottomano!

In cosa consiste questa "prova finestra" di cui si parla nel testo? Fa riferimento a qualche pubblicità di detersivi? Una ricerca su Google mi ha fatto vedere che si tratta di un'espressione che si usa abbastanza, ma non ho trovato niente sulla sua origine.

Quello che ho trovato su Google però mi ha fatto pensare a una [pubblicità spagnola di un prodotto per pulire le piastrelle](https://youtube.com/watch?v=nsnIpoZVA_8) nella quale appariva l'espressione "la prueba del algodón" (la prova del batuffolo di cotone): adesso a volte si usa questa espressione in spagnolo con un significato simile a quello della locuzione "la prova del fuoco" usata in senso figurato. È successo qualcosa di simile con l'espressione "la prova finestra"?

Comment: Non mi dice nulla, ma visto che si tratta di un'opera del 1970, è possibile che fosse un riferimento a una pubblicità popolare al tempo ma oggi sconosciuta ai più. L'altra possibilità che mi viene in mente è che potrebbe essere un eufemismo per "gettare fuori dalla finestra ogni anarchico". O forse anche tutte e due le cose insieme, con effetto umoristico.

Comment: https://books.google.dk/books?id=bnFASqLuF2AC&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=prova+finestra+sole&source=bl&ots=Agqvy7oe_e&sig=wW98ANmlFndaA2vyYxVzX6ltCq8&hl=da&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL8qLyyaPRAhUJ2CwKHbHoCoUQ6AEIOTAH#v=onepage&q=prova%20finestra%20sole&f=false

Comment: È sicuramente come dice Federico: usa un termine simil-pubblicitario per fare un amaro riferimento alla morte di Pinelli.

Comment: @DaG:Questo posso immaginarlo, ma sembra che adesso se ne stia facendo un uso figurato simile a quello della "prova del fuoco".

Comment: @DaG: Per esempio: http://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2015/01/31/mattarella-presidente-prova-finestra-credibilita-internazionale/1387230/, http://www.nextquotidiano.it/prova-finestra-sulle-banche-italiane/, http://www.lanuovabq.it/mobile/articoli-la-via-lombarda-per-fare-la-prova-finestra-alle-lobby-16766.htm#.WGppKp8o80M.

Comment: Se ne parla qui: http://www.treccani.it/90anni/parole/1974-scottex.html.

Comment: Se ne parla anche qui: http://www.01net.it/prova-finestra/.

Comment: Suppongo siano le pubblicità che appaiono qui (si parla dell'"esame-finestra"): http://curiosando708090.altervista.org/cera-volta-tide-dal-1943/.

Comment: Per il niente che conta, non ho mai sentito “prova finestra”, ma sia questo contesto che un contesto non politicizzato renderebbero chiaro che cosa si intende, più o meno.

Answer (score 3):

La pubblicità c'entra solo di striscio.

L'allusione è a una *non provata* pratica attribuita alla questura di Milano, in particolare durante le indagini sull'[attentato alla Banca dell'Agricoltura in piazza Fontana a Milano del 12 dicembre 1969.](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strage_di_piazza_Fontana)

Il riferimento è chiaramente alla morte di Giuseppe Pinelli, caduto da una finestra della questura. Per molto tempo ne fu ritenuto responsabile il commissario Luigi Calabresi, poi assassinato da esponenti di Lotta Continua, secondo varie sentenze passate in giudicato. [Il testo di Dario Fo è una “ricostruzione” di quegli avvenimenti](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morte_accidentale_di_un_anarchico); del tutto personale e che gli costò parecchie denunce, tanto che l'ambientazione fu trasferita negli Stati Uniti.

Dubito che quando oggi si sente “prova finestra” si faccia riferimento al testo di Fo. Non ricordo quale pubblicità di detersivo proponeva alla massaia la “prova finestra” per dimostrare che il pulito era evidente anche se il tessuto era messo davanti alla finestra, cioè in piena luce: al giorno d'oggi significa semplicemente “prova definitiva e irrefutabile”.

Comment: Io direi che c'entrino entrambe le cose: è ovvio il riferimento alla morte di Pinelli (come dici giustamente vi è incentrato tutto il testo, fin dal titolo) ma, perché abbia senso la battuta “prova finestra”, o fa riferimento a una pubblicità specifica o almeno deve suonare come linguaggio pubblicitario/televisivo.

Comment: @egreg: Tutto questo lo so. Forse non sono riuscita a spiegarmi bene, ma la mia domanda è soltanto sull'espressione "prova finestra" che sembra fare riferimento a qualche pubblicità dal momento che Dario Fo scrive "propagandatori di detersivi".

Comment: Sembra che la pubblicità sia quella che appare in alcune delle immagini di [questo sito](http://curiosando708090.altervista.org/cera-volta-tide-dal-1943/) in cui si parla dell'"esame-finestra". Volevo semplicemente sapere in cosa consisteva questa "prova finestra" nella pubblicità, ma penso si capisca bene guardano queste immagine.

Comment: Nella domanda ho chiesto anche sull'uso che si fa adesso di questa espressione: da quanto ho trovato su Google, sembra avere un uso figurato simile a quello della locuzione "la prova del fuoco".

Comment: @Charo L'uso attuale è quello della pubblicità: una prova “definitiva”.

Comment: @egreg: Guarda le immagini di [questo sito](http://curiosando708090.altervista.org/cera-volta-tide-dal-1943/).

Comment: @Charo Sì, potrebbe essere il Tide (pronunciato come se fosse una parola italiana, all'epoca). Fu anche il primo a mettere figurine e altre cose nelle confezioni, tanto che si diceva, di qualcosa di mediocre o basso costo, “l'hai trovato nel Tide?”

Comment: Quindi, l'uso attuale (che molto probabilmente fa riferimento alla pubblicità di detersivo e non al testo di Fo) è in certo modo simile a quello dell'espressione ["la prova del fuoco"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fuoco/)?

Comment: Lo menziona anche [questo sito](http://www.treccani.it/90anni/parole/1974-scottex.html) (cerca "prova-finestra").

Comment: Che infatti fa una citazione a questo libro: https://books.google.es/books?id=0lXgrxEwaAoC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=prova-finestra+detersivo+Tide&source=bl&ots=wlY5N_9sxx&sig=FCpGXuK04DH2CDqmuby5WcW841E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbmpvGjKTRAhUD1hQKHS4kCB4Q6AEIETAC#v=onepage&q=prova-finestra%20detersivo%20Tide&f=false.

Comment: @Charo Be', chiaramente “prova-finestra” o “esame-finestra” allude a cose simili alla prova del fuoco o al giudizio divino.

Answer (score 0):

Credo faccia riferimento a qualche battuta prima, in cui (se non ricordo male) si parla di come il poliziotto fosse solito far sporgere dalla finestra un sospettato invitandolo a buttarsi giù nella speranza di terrorizzarlo e spingerlo a confessare. Cito:
«Il Commissario del quarto piano mi ha schiaffato a sedere sulla finestra le gambe penzoloni, e poi ha cominciato a provocarmi: buttati e mi insultava... perché non ti butti... non ne hai il coraggio, eh? E falla finita! Cosa aspetti? Vi assicuro che ho dovuto stringere i denti per non soccombere per non lasciarmi andare...»

Comment: A quanto abbiamo trovato, sembra si faccia riferimento a qualche pubblicità del detersivo Tide.

Comment: Sicuri? Io ho trovato la battuta che lo riguardava.

Comment: L'ho capito, è solo che, avendolo letto anche io, sono convinto si tratti di un'allusione a questa "pratica".